# Detectar ellipsis

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma seguinte `div` com uma imagem, o título e algumas opções. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.truncate {
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="item thumb">
  <div class="thumbnail"><img src="../img/img.png" />
    <div class="caption truncate" style="width: 100px">
      <span>Negreiros supermercados</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">5 lojas</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de ao passar o mouse em cima do título e tiver as reticencias `[...]`, somente se tiver reticências, aparecesse o título completo em um `Tooltip`(por exemplo). Qual maneira mais simples de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

A mais simples de todas seria passar o texto atraves do atributo title

```css
.truncate {
  font-size: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="item thumb">
  <div class="thumbnail"><img src="../img/img.png" />
    <div class="caption truncate" title="Negreiros supermercados" style="width: 100px">
      <span>Negreiros supermercados</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">5 lojas</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas assim, caso o texto esteja mostrando completamente, eu não precisaria do atributo title

Comment: Mas se o título for exibido por completo, ninguém vai precisar parar o mouse em cima pra ler o `title`, que não vai fazer diferença.

Comment: exato, o fato do texto estar completamente visivel, não faz com que se faça necessário inibir o title pois ele é um elemento que demanda uma interação do usuário.